# C++ STL list's Push_back takes argument pass by value?

Tags: c++, stl

c++ STL::list 's push_back function takes arguments as pass-by-value . But still am able to access the list's elements when the arguments are going out of scope.

```
 typedef std::list<MyObject> mylist;
 void function1()
 {
     MyObject obj;<<<< local scope
    ...
     mylist.push_back(obj);
 }

void function2()
{

//On Iterating the list "mylist" able to access objs in the list properly even though the scope of obj is lost in function1.

}
```

Comment: [No.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back)

Comment: Google should be *way before* Stack Overflow in your prioritised list of "where to get help." But since you asked about the STL, [no, it's passed by const reference](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html). And the same holds for the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back).

Comment: Sorry May be the question is not complete! I was confused as the prototype is taking a reference but i was still able to access list elements while the arguments lost their scope!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function signature is

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

and the value passed is copied in your list. So you can consider this a "pass-by-value" (in a operational way).
In C++11 you have also

```
void push_back (value_type&& val);
```

that is a possibilities of move your value into your list.

Answer (score 2):

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
void push_back (value_type&& val);
```

The first signature takes a const reference but will copy it. The second takes an rvalue-reference and will move it.

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/

Answer (score 1):

It should be pass-by-reference:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/